def __del__(self) is automatically called and i don't know how to stop it
So I am learning to program with python at the moment and right now i am learning about classes/objects. as per the tutorials I found the __del__(self) method should only be called when i use the keyword "del" + variable but the method somehow calls itself
here is the code:
class person:
    def __init__(self, name, subclass, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.subclass = subclass
        self.gender = gender

    def __del__(self):
        print(f"{self.name} deleted.")

xardas = person("Xardas", "Necromancer", "male")
print(xardas.name)
print(xardas.subclass)
print(xardas.gender)

here is the output:
Xardas
Necromancer
male
Xardas deleted.

I didn't expect the last line.
Adding del xardas at the end of the code doesn't do anything apparent.
Adding xardas.__del__() results in the following output:
Xardas
Necromancer
male
Xardas deleted.
Xardas deleted.


Based on the above comment, this means that since the code finishes execution, the last thing to do is removing the class instance, resulting in __del__ being called, right?

This is actually intended role of __del__()! It's for cleanup, and when main script ends everything will be gracefully deleted, hence it's called! If you want it live a bit longer just add time.sleep(10) at the end or use python interactive session!

"as per the tutorials I found the __del__(self) method should only be called when i use the keyword "del" + variable" no, that is totally incorrect. This is all explained in the documentation where this is explicitly addressed

@jupiterbjy no, it's actually not the intended use case at all!  You can read the warning in the docs: "It is not guaranteed that __del__() methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits. weakref.finalize provides a straightforward way to register a cleanup function to be called when an object is garbage collected."

basically, don't rely on __del__, you probably should not use it at all, and also, it is crucial to understand that __del__ doesn't have anything to do with del

@RadekD nope, it is not guaranteed that __del__ will be called for objects that are alive during interpreter shutdown.

@juanpa.arrivillaga yes I know it is not guranteed but there isn't any better option out there are they? try-finally outside the class is all I can think of which still is not guranteed for some cases. Wish they gave better dunder method for this.

@jupiterbjy generally you want to use context-managers and not rely on finalizers.

@jupiterbjy,  If a context manager isn't possible, then the data model documentation suggests using weakref.finalize to register any necessary clean up functions.  They will always be run when the interpreter exits, while __del__ is not guaranteed to execute.

@nigh_anxiety that's neat, thanks. However I can't shake the feeling that this is overly complicated for supposed to be natural thing haha..

The tutorial you are using is mistaken on the usage of __del__.
__del__ will sometimes get called when you use del, but that's circumstantial.
The __del__ dunder method gets called when the reference count of an object reaches 0.
Consider the following (using your person class):
bob = person("Bob", "Fighter", "Male")
party = [bob]
del bob
print("ending program")

This will output
ending program
Bob deleted

Because the list party is maintaining a reference to the Bob person instance until the program exits.
However, it also isn't guaranteed that __del__ will be called when the interpreter exits.  I would suggest reading the official documentation for __del__ here.
This video also has a good discussion of the topic: Python's most DISLIKED __dunder__ (and what to use instead) by mCoding

yeah, exactly correct. __del__ is a really unfortunate part of the data model, that probably should have never been made, although, I once used it for debugging (that code base was a mess...)
